# Regex find beginning and end strings with special charaters

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

We are trying to remove tons of special charaters from URL strings.
Most contain TM or Copyright symbol, as well as some others.

I wanted to write a regex to find the begining "&" and the ending ";" and remove the entire string.

I have written:

```
var title = "RedHorseBar&trade;"   
title = Regex.Replace(title, @"^\&.*\;$", "");
```

Hopeing to get "RedHorseBar" .. but it is not working.

How do I write regex to find the begining "&" and the ending ";"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following: `&[^;]+;`

So, to use it in the way you want:

```
title = Regex.Replace(title, @"&[^;]+;", "")
```

Comment: for the .NET library, you don't need to delimit with `/` or specify global `g`.

Comment: Ah... good to know @Matthew.  I'm not familiar with the specifics of that library.  I'll edit the answer to account for that.

Comment: @DavidKEgghead - outside of .NET having some special escaping requirements that I'm not aware of, i'm not sure what to tell you.  The pattern works as far as I understand what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
title = Regex.Replace(title, @"&.*;", "")
```

You don't need to specify *match start* (^) and *match end* ($) characters, because the string you want to replace doesn't begin with the start of string or end (maybe) with the end of string.

Comment: That is going to greedily consume characters.  Won't work if two such special entities are present, for example: Red&amp;HorseBar&trade;

Comment: @Daedalus You are right, but it seems that this is what David wants.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you were looking for something like & nbsp; etc.

Then the regex should be something like this: &\w+;

But you seems to be looking for the string without the special chars., then you should:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(title, @"&\w+;", "");
```

I hope this helps you in your quest.